# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' -PyTorch

Tags: python

```
class Flowers(data.Dataset):
def __init__(self, txt, transform=None, target_transform=None, loader=default_loader):
    super(Flowers, self).__init__()
    fh = open(txt, 'r')
    images = []
    for line in fh:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        line = line.rsplit()
        words = line.split()
        words = str(list.split)
        images.append((words[0], int(words[1])))
    self.imgs = images
    self.transform = transform
    self.target_transform = target_transform
    self.loader = loader
```

As the code above, I am trying to read my picture dataset via a text filled with paths. However, I got a error like this:

```
File "/Users/paulwang/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/VGGNet.py", line 130, in <module>
    train_data = Flowers(txt='/Users/paulwang/Desktop/flower_photos_train/train.txt', transform=transform)
  File "/Users/paulwang/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/VGGNet.py", line 100, in __init__
    words = line.split()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I've gone through some similar questions but I still can't figure out how to solve this problem. I am sincerely looking for help.

Comment: The `rsplit()` method splits a string into a list, starting from the right. So you can't split it again since it's a list now(not a string).

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this pair of statements:

```
    line = line.rsplit()
```

`line` was a string up until now.  You just turned it into a list of strings.  Therefore, when you try the next line:

```
    words = line.split()
```

You're trying an illegal operation.
Worse, in the next line, you destroy the result of this second line and replace it with the string representation of the `split` method.

I strongly recommend that you repeat your tutorial on string processing.  Then work through your coding again. After each one or two lines you write, add a `print` to verify the type and value of the prior statements.